# How to get $(this) selected option in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works:

```
$("#select-id").change(function(){
  var cur_value = $('#select-id option:selected').text();
  . . .
});
```

How to refactor the second line to:

```
var cur_value = $(this).***option-selected***.text();
```

What do you use for `***option-selected***`?

Answer (score 144):

For the selected value: `$(this).val()`

If you need the selected option element, `$("option:selected", this)`

Comment: This selector provides a jQ object, so add `.text()` gets its text [`$("option:selected", this).text()`]

Answer (score 133):

```
 $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - I tried `$("option:selected", this)` as mentioned above but that was problematic. I was using a button click to append the selected option element text to another div, but when I clicked the button, it actually changed the selected element... weird.  Use this one.

Answer (score 64):

Best and shortest way in my opinion for onchange events on the dropdown to get the selected option:

```
$('option:selected',this);
```

to get the value attribute:

```
$('option:selected',this).attr('value');
```

to get the shown part between the  tags:

```
$('option:selected',this).text();
```

In your sample:

```
$("#select-id").change(function(){
  var cur_value = $('option:selected',this).text();
});
```

Comment: Don't use `.context`, it is deprecated since jQuery 1.10 - http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.10/

Comment: Yep, but what you mean is this:

http://api.jquery.com/context/


$( "ul", document.body ).context.nodeName

which i don´t use

Comment: I like the answer but why it is best ?

Answer (score 49):

```
var cur_value = $('option:selected',this).text();
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 14):

This should work:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Comment: Same answer as above

Comment: Posted within the same minute!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `find` to look for the selected option that is a descendant of the node(s) pointed to by the current jQuery object:

```
var cur_value = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Since this is likely an immediate child, I would actually suggest using `.children` instead:

```
var cur_value = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var cur_value = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Since `option` is likely to be immediate child of `select` you can also use:

```
var cur_value = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Where do you get `option-selected` with no quotes...?

Comment: That was a typo when I posted. Corrected the answer.

Comment: `find('option:selected')` returns an empty string for me. What version of jQuery is required? I am working in 1.6.1. `children('option:selected')` does work.

Comment: `option:selected` has been there since v1.0 http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 1):

It's just

```
$(this).val();
```

I think jQuery is clever enough to know what you need

Answer (score 0):

Best guess:

```
var cur_value = $('#select-id').children('option:selected').text();
```

I like children better in this case because you know you're only going one branch down the DOM tree...

Comment: Maybe what you really meant was var cur_value = $(this).children('option:selected').text();