# Modify img sibling after selecting an option

Tags: jquery, replace, siblings

I cannot figure out how to compress this code to make it DRY. It works fine with different elements or when repeating code, but I want to keep it clean. This is the html:

```
<div class = "face left">
  <img src = "/images/faces/empty.jpg"><br>
  <select>
    <option value="empty">Select one</option>
    <option value="ab18e97e6c64f8db588e95772daf51b4">Takeshi</option>
    <option value="d27b579c196202648ba7c4b1904e8e20">Osuka</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class = "face right">
  <img src = "/images/faces/empty.jpg"><br>
  <select>
    <option value="empty">Select one</option>
    <option value="ab18e97e6c64f8db588e95772daf51b4">Takeshi</option>
    <option value="d27b579c196202648ba7c4b1904e8e20">Osuka</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The not working jquery I've got so far:

```
$('.face').children('select').change(function()
   {
   $(this).
     siblings('img').
     replaceWith('<img src = "/ajax/faces/' + $(this).siblings('select option:selected').attr('value') + '">');
   });
```

I want to achieve that, when I change the select, the img of that div gets replaced for a new one (with the src dynamically created from the value of the choosen option). I can get it to kind of work if I do this (deleting the `$(this).siblings`):

```
$('.face').children('select').change(function()
   {
   $(this).
     siblings('img').
     replaceWith('<img src = "/ajax/faces/' + $('select option:selected').attr('value') + '">');
   });
```

But with that code I can only have one 'face', and I actually want two. So, **how can I modify my jquery code to replace it's sibling `<img>` and not to affect other ones?** The first code doesn't work because it tries to find the image `/ajax/faces/undefined`.

Comment: I tend to have problems tracking what `$(this)` is in this kind of situation.  Try storing `$(this)` or the desired siblings of `$(this)` before the `replaceWith`.

Comment: Me too, I'm just learning jquery so far and having trouble without the `echo` or `var_dump` from PHP. However even storing it I cannot make it much better. I don't think dumping all my failed attempts will improve much my question...

Comment: I could solve it finally changing my point of view! I will write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.face > select').change(function()
   {
   $(this).
     siblings('img').attr('src', '/ajax/faces/' + $(this).val());
   });
```

The main problem with your code is that the options are not siblings, they're children, so you should have used `find()`. But the value of the selected option is also the value of the select, so that can be simplified away entirely.

And rather than replace the entire `<img>` element, I just replace the `src` attribute of the existing element.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/FHdJY/2/)

Comment: It looks good, but it says `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` and pointing to the longest line.

Comment: @Barmar, looks like you have an extra `)` after `val()`.

Comment: I don't know why, but it simply [doesn't seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/FHdJY/1/)...

Comment: The problem was because I replaced `siblings` with `prev`. The previous element is `<br>`, I didn't notice that.

Comment: I just got to the same code (as in your last edit) with your previous code and what I had, I will accept it then. Thank you so much! (:

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that siblings does not return the element it is called on.  In this case, `$(this)` was the selector, so `$(this).siblings('select')` returns nothing.  There are also a few ways that you could clean up your code.  `<select>` elements have a value assigned to them, so you can simply use `$('select').val()`.  It may also be pertinent to use the `on()` function.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/astex/pxmkv/) is some jsFiddle solving a very similar problem.

Comment: `$(this)` doesn't change its value unless you pass a function to `replaceWith()`.

Answer (score 0):

After about 1 hour digging and now from a different point of view, I could solve it. This is the solution that worked for me, thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10011802/938236):

```
$('.face').children('select').change(function()
 {
 $(this).
   siblings('img').
   replaceWith('<img src = "/ajax/faces/' + $("option:selected", this).attr('value') + '">');
  });
```

[And here is a working version of what I wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/FHdJY/) (with random internet faces).

Note: although I am answering, since there has been a couple of much better answers since I started writting this, I will accept one of them.